# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException:

Tags: java

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
public boolean deleteBook(String callno, String studentid) {

    boolean userFounds= false;

    Session session=this.sessionFactory.openSession();
     System.out.println("check update:"+callno);
     System.out.println("check update:"+studentid);


        // delete operation
    String SQL_QUERY2 ="delete from IssueBook where callno= ? and studentid=?"; 

    Query query= session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY2);

     query.setParameter(0, callno).executeUpdate();
     query.setParameter(1, studentid).executeUpdate();
     return userFounds;

    }
```

i am getting 500-server exception
on  here 
     query.setParameter(0, callno).executeUpdate();
         query.setParameter(1, studentid).executeUpdate();

**See stacktrace:**

[image: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter count: 2, actual parameters: [1002] [delete from IssueBook where callno= ? and studentid=?]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String SQL_QUERY2 ="delete from IssueBook where callno=:callno and studentid=:studentid";
Query query= session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY2);
     query.setParameter(callno, callno);
     query.setParameter(studentid, studentid);
     return query.executeUpdate();
```

The issue in your code is executeUpdate() should be invoked once after setting all the parameters.